# If column values matches, then paste TRUE in next corresponding column

Tags: excel

I have one Excel file with below values:

```
#GROUP  DATA

A1
A2
A1
A3
A4
```

I am not getting the excel formula so that if the value in Group column is "A1" then in DATA it should paste TRUE, else FALSE

Expected -

```
#GROUP  DATA

A1  TRUE
A2  FALSE
A1  TRUE
A3  FALSE
A4  FALSE
```

Please, I need some ideas on how to do this

Comment: You mean something like `IF(A1="A1";TRUE;FALSE)` and drag down?

Comment: Yes...looking for the same

Comment: Could you please post an example of the expected output? It's kind of unclear what you asking

Comment: `=A2="A1"` .. Simple line will print that.  Drag it down.

Comment: Then, what I said in my first comment will work perfectly. Try it

Comment: Tried, it is giving something wrong with formula in popup

Comment: *it is giving something wrong* it's unclear. Can you specify more what type of error? Also, this formula is really simple and basic, so it should not be so hard to apply it

Comment: @Sandy, are you looking for it to say TRUE if the value on the first column appears more than once? Or for it to say TRUE if the value is "A1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the expected results be like?

Expected -

```
#GROUP  DATA

A1      TRUE
A2      TRUE
A1      TRUE
A3      FALSE
A4      FALSE
A2      TRUE
```

If I understood correctly you want to know if the value appears in the column more than once, as such the CountIf formula can help here, you could do something like the following, enter the formula on Cell B1 and then Fill Down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: *you want to know if the value appears in the column more than once* why? OP posted the expected output as an example. Just a list of true/false. How can that be a count?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns You can see that the second A1 is also TRUE in their expected outcome, meaning that they are actually looking to see if the value does indeed appear more than once in the column, I think the question itself is a little confusing.

Answer (score 2):

**Use this:**

`=A2="A1"` and drag it down.

[image]

Comment: It should fill by own

Comment: What do you mean by Fill by Own ?

Comment: @Sandy .. You have to write a Code for that. Try googling it, Look for loops in VBA.

Comment: @Sandy Once you have several lines filled in, Excel should automatically start doing the "filldown" when you add items at the bottom of column A

Comment: Or Maybe just don't drag. Double click on the Right Down Corner of the First formula cell and it will autofill all the cells.

Comment: @Xabier .. Am i misunderstanding the question ? It is producing results as expected in the question.

Comment: @Mikku just look at their expected outcome for the second A1, it shows as TRUE as the value does appear on the column more than once, I think the question is a little confusing, but they are looking to see if the value does exist more than once on the column....

Comment: @Xabier .. I think it's just a plain and simple check of if cell value equals `A1`

Comment: @Mikku, my bad then, the Question seems a little ambiguous, I understood something different...

Comment: @Xabier .. No worries  ... I can be wrong as well.

Comment: I think all of us are confused because OP should clarify.